# The arrays automatically change within the subroutine they have readed

Tags: arrays, fortran, arguments, subroutine

Im not expert but I'm writing a code using Absoft Fortran 2016. 
Briefly: It seems the arrays write on each other or maybe they use the same part of memory. 
I figured out that the output values are not rational, After some inspections I found that there is a problem with arrays.I simplified the code to the part which faced problem. There is a main body and 2 subroutines. The first subroutine (SubInput0) read the basic data and the second one (SubInput1) read the detailed data. In SubInput1 some coordinates should be read from some files. they are read correctly, but at immediate next loop the values are start changing! I mean, while the next loop is reading the next array, the previous array also changed, although there is no link between them. The outputs show the next array is writing itself on the previous one. This really confused me.

Thanks for your help.

I tried different ways to declare the arrays differently, also to declare or not to declare arrays within the body,tried different implicit approaches.

```
SubRoutine Control()
!THIS SUBROUTINE CONTROLS THE PROGRAM
!==================================================
  Common /A/NNP,NODB3
  Common /A1/NB3,NNPBED3,NNE,NNPEN
  Common /C/NLoad,NTime,ITime,DTime
  Common /E/GRAV

    Real,Dimension(2,NNP)   :: X
    Real,Dimension(2,NNE)   :: XEncl
    Real,Dimension(3)       :: MATERIAL

    Open (10,FILE=Input.TXT)              !Open Input File
Open (20,FILE=Output.TXT)             !Open Output File
Open (30,FILE='Log.txt')              !Open Log File
Open (40,FILE='Node.txt')             !Open Node Coordinate File
Open (50,FILE='Encl.txt')             !Open Encl Node Coordinate File

!--------Calling Sub Routines

!==============================              
    Call SubInput0 ()                     !Call Sub to read the basic info             
!==============================  
!==============================              
    Call SubInput1 (X,XEncl,MATERIAL)     !Call Sub to read the Details             
!==============================   

RETURN 
END
```

The SubRoutine SubInput0

```
SubRoutine SubInput0()
!This SubRoutine Reads The Basic Data From The Input Files

! Commons -----------------------------------------
  Common /A/NNP,NODB3
  Common /A1/NB3,NNPBED3,NNE,NNPEN
  Common /C/NLoad,NTime,ITime,DTime
  Common /E/GRAV
!--------------------------------------------------      
Character*10 C$

Write(*,*) "SubInput0 Started"        

    Read(10,*) C$                        ! Read Project Name       
    Read(10,*) NNP                       ! Read Num of total Nodes
    Read(10,*) NNPBED3,NNPEN
    Read(10,*) NLOAD,NTIME,DTime         ! Read Num of Load and Time Steps

    Grav=9.81

  NB3=NNPBED3
  NNE=NNPEN

RETURN 
End
```

The SubRoutine SubInput1

```
SubRoutine SubInput1(X,XEncl,MATERIAL)
!This SubRoutine Reads The Basic Data From The Input Files

! Commons -----------------------------------------
  Common /A/NNP,NODB3
  Common /A1/NB3,NNPBED3,NNE,NNPEN
  Common /C/NLoad,NTime,ITime,DTime
  Common /E/GRAV
!-------------------------------------------------- 

    Real,Dimension(2,NNP), intent(out)   :: X
    Real,Dimension(2,NNE), intent(out)   :: XEncl
    Real,Dimension(3),     intent(out)   :: MATERIAL


Write(*,*) "SubInput1 Started"        

    Do i=1,NNP
    read(40,*) NN,X(1,i),X(2,i)          ! First it's readed correctly
    Enddo

    Do i=1,NNE
    read(50,*) NE,XEncl(1,i),XEncl(2,i)  ! But here the X will also change
    Enddo

!Read Material Data------------------------------
    Read(10,*) MATERIAL(1),MATERIAL(2),MATERIAL(3) 
                                   ! Also here both X and XEncl change
!------------------------------------------------
RETURN 
END
```

X values, immediately after its read in first loop which are correct:

-100.000  0.000000 -80.0000  0.000000 -60.0000  0.000000 -40.0000  0.000000 -20.0000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  20.0000  0.000000  40.0000  0.000000  60.0000  0.000000  80.0000  0.000000  100.000  0.000000

X values, after The Second Loop which are incorrect:

-100.000 -20.0000 -100.000 -40.0000 -100.000 -60.0000 -100.000 -80.0000 -100.000 -100.000 -80.0000 -100.000 -60.0000 -100.000 -40.0000 -100.000 -20.0000 -100.000  0.000000 -100.000  20.0000 -100.000

XEncl Values which I think some how are related to changed values of X:

-100.000 -20.0000 -100.000 -40.0000 -100.000 -60.0000 -100.000 -80.0000 -100.000 -100.000 -80.0000 -100.000 -60.0000 -100.000 -40.0000 -100.000 -20.0000 -100.000  0.000000 -100.000  20.0000 -100.000  40.0000 -100.000  60.0000 -100.000  80.0000 -100.000  100.000 -100.000  100.000 -80.0000  100.000 -60.0000  100.000 -40.0000  100.000 -20.0000

Comment: It looks as if procedure argument checking would complain. With use of Module you wouldn't have this option of skipping standard compliance. Can't say if this is the problem

Comment: Indeed, please enable all debugging options and warnings your compiler offers and you can even try to use a module for the subroutines, it should be quite a simple change.

Comment: I've enabled all debugging options and nothing is wrong, I also moved both subroutines in a module, however when the subroutine is called, the problem still exist. I dont know what is the problem, but for now maybe i can fix it, defining different parts of memory for each array, or may 1 array with more dimensions.